# Unable to connect to mobile broadband.. But it is detected

Tags: 10.10, internet, modem

Mobile broadband (Tata photon network )is detected and shows in the connections system tray but it does not connect to the Internet.

Comment: did you create a new connection for tata photon using network manager? or it is detecting as storage device.

Comment: It is showing as configured in the network connections. But when  I try to connect it shows not enabled! :(

Comment: Yes, I have created a new connection.

Comment: does `Enable mobile broadband` has tick mark? its in end of network manager aplet menu

Comment: @Sowmya: Install `wvdial` using `sudo apt-get install wvdial` and than follow the instructions given on [wvidal archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wvdial) to generate its config file.

Answer (score 0):

Use wvdial. Automatic detect USB modem and disable storage.

Comment: I'm a newbie to Ubuntu.. :( How do I install wvdial now?

Comment: Indeed, this answer would be much improved by explaining how to do that.

Comment: Go TO: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wvdial
My config:
`[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Modem Type = Analog Modem
ISDN = 0
New PPPD = yes
Phone = *99***1#
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Username = wap
Password = wap
Baud = 115200
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.t-mobile.cz"
`
My use:
`Run - xterm - sudo wvdial` My modem is connected ... :)

Comment: If you want to automatically connect when you turn on .. works even when disconnec/connec USB 3G modem.
Create your script in the directory /script gsm.sh or script of your choice ..
`chmod 777 /script/gsm.sh`
gsm.sh contains
`#! /bin/bash
(
   while : ; do
       wvdial
       sleep 60
   done
) &`
Now put the whole script in / etc / rc.local
`/script/gsm.sh exit 0`

Comment: While I'm running: wvdial /etc/wvdial.conf and I get a message saying "Sorry no modem was detected.!" whilst modem is connected.

Comment: I still haven't got it working.. Somebody help! :(